# How to chart two metrics from aggregated table in Looker?

Tags: data-visualization, looker

I am trying to make a line chart with two metrics vs date. I am querying an already aggregated table. When I add three columns to the visualization, date and 2 numeric fields and pick scatter plot or line chart, only two numeric fields are charted. I want to be able to chart date as X axis and two numeric fields as line chart.

Is there a way to chart two numeric dimensions in one chart without aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one dimension, which is the date, and two measures with **type:number** (because you don't need any aggregation)

```
  measure: total_amount {
    type: number
    sql: ${pre_aggregated_total_amount} ;;

  measure: product_count {
    type: number
    sql: ${pre_aggregated_product_count} ;;
```

Also, in the line chart option, you will be able to drag one measure to the left axis and the other one to the right axis if you want.

[image]